# Using "exhausts" in relation to a plant

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to use the plural "exhausts" in relation to a plant or a factory rather than a vehicle?

For example, would it be okay to say:

> The residents' healths have been deteriorating lately due to the
> exhausts coming from the recently built paper factory right in the
> middle of the town.

I googled "exhausts coming from" and I saw that in almost all of the results it is only about cars, so I am not sure.

Comment: [Emissions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/emission) is more usual.

Comment: ...and it would be more usual to say 'The residents' health has been deteriorating'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey not only more usual but the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a countable noun, "an exhaust" is a pipe that takes  *exhaust gas* from a motor engine.

There is some use of "exhaust" as a non-coutable noun. It usually refers to the fumes from a motor engine, and not pollution from a smokestack.  In your context, it is probably better to say "pollution" "emissions" or "smoke" (in general terms) or use a chemical term, such as "PFAs" (perfluorinated alkyl) if you are being specific.